# Which windows version is best compatible with wine?

Tags: windows, wine

I am applying to do some online consulting work with a company that states "having a computer with Windows OS" as a requirement. I don't have Windows but I hope to use their software under Wine. In the application form they ask the following question:

> What is the version of Microsoft Windows installed in your computer?
>
> - Windows 8.1
> - Windows 8
> - Windows 7
> - Windows Vista
> - Other

Which version should I state in order to maximize the chance that I can run their software under Wine?

Comment: Did my answer resolve your question? I'm curious to know if that's what you wanted to know.

Comment: Yes, your answer was helpful, thanks! I was asking for somebody else and was waiting for their feedback before accepting.

Comment: Ah, glad to have helped. I wasn't sure if that would help or not, glad to see that it's useful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [WineHQ - About Wine](https://www.winehq.org/about/) page:

> Wine began in 1993 under the initial coordination of Bob Amstadt as a
>   way to support running Windows 3.1 programs on Linux. Very early on,
>   leadership over Wine's development passed to Alexandre Julliard, who
>   has managed the project ever since. Over the years, as the Windows API
>   and applications have evolved to take advantage of new hardware and
>   software, Wine has adapted to support new features, all while being
>   ported to other OSes, becoming more stable, and providing a better
>   user-experience.

From that it sounds like there really is no *specific* version of Windows that WINE is based off of.

However, if you run `wine regedit` and then navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` > `Software` > `Microsoft` > `Windows NT`:

[image]

and select the `CurrentVersion` key:

[image]

you'll see a registry string titled `ProductName`.

In my case, running Wine 1.6.2, the value for `ProductName` is `Windows XP`. Then, looking at the `CSDVersion` string's value, you'll notice that it says `Service Pack 3`.

Thus, your safest bet would most likely be that Wine is most similar to Windows XP (Service Pack 3).

**EDIT**

I've discovered something else in WINE. If you install `winetricks` and then open it up, then click on **Select the default wineprefix**:

[image]

Then click **Run winecfg**:

[image]

You can change the version of Windows that WINE, I guess, emulates? You can change the displayed Windows version at the very least:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't change what wine version is emulated; it simply changes what version of windows Wine reports itself as to programs that check what version of windows they are being run on.